# Disable php for all sub Subdirectorys only with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need disable php script in sub folder only not in root index.php .

for example my files :

```
index.php
test.php
1/index.php
2/index.php
class/*.php
2/test.php
.../... .php
```

I want disable all php file except index.php in root and class dir .

i try for index root :

```
php_flag engine off

<Files index.php>
    php_flag engine on
</Files>
```

But this enable all file with `index.php` .

now how I can disable all sub folder expect class and all file expect index.php in root ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it. Why would you need to have PHP files in a directory if only to disable the PHP processing of the files. Rename the files .txt or something and lock the directory permissions so no one can access it.

Comment: Thank you but in need ignore them with Apache handler.

Comment: `php_flag engine off

<Files /var/www/test/index.php>
    php_flag engine on
</Files>`